# Magento product URL shows Manufacturer and SKU, I want it to show the title

Tags: php, magento, url, title

need some help. At the moment product url is like 
my site. com/hp-f7y90ea-acb-1711.html

It shows manufacturer, SKU code and price. However, I would like the url to be like:
 my site. com/HP-350 G1-i5-4200-15,6-HD-AG-HD4400-4GB-500GB-DVD-BT-Silve

I am new to magento, which file do I need to edit and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Goto `admin>System>configuration>Catalog>Search Engine Optimizations`

Here  you have find `Product URL Suffix` field make it blank.
Which is remove .html from url

Then set Product url
try below

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/manufacturer-in-product-url-key/24878#24878

Comment: Thanks for the information, however, I couldn't find the paths specified in url provided..

Answer (score 0):

4200-15,6-HD-AG  , in url is not acceptable.

you need to write your own rewrite url module or use Magento rewrite admin interface.but with admin interface you will have to do a lot of data entry.